# How to add a spinner in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to add a spinner in my fragment by using "double" instead of "String". I know, my code is not correct at all! But I came here to seek for another solution.

```
// Declaration
Spinner spinner;
double[] Array_note = {1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6};
ArrayAdapter<double> adapter;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cofo, container,
false);

spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.Sp_F_Note);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ouble>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Array_note);
}
```

I hope someone can help me out :)

Comment: please learn java's basics: `double` != `Double`

Comment: I appreciate your answer for that correction... However, I don't know how to do this with "double". 
I've seen a lot of examples on internet with "String" but not with "double".

Comment: ArrayAdapter<double> nor [`ArrayList<double>` will not even compile](https://ideone.com/2KpKip) ... java's basics: generics

Comment: Yes, I know... I tried them and I realized that none of them work. Now I'm here, seeking for another solution..

Comment: since `double != Double` then changing `double[] Array_note = {1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6};`  to `Double[] Array_note = {1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.5,5.0,5.5,6.0};` would obviously help ... but, yeah, I know it's too compilcated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In array Adapter only class type is use can not use data type .

try to this code:

```
 List<Double> list=new ArrayList<>();
        double i=1.0;
        while(i<=6.0)
        {
            list.add(i);
            i=i+0.5;
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Double> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(getactivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Use this code it's help me show double value in spinner.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness! I'm going to use this and to see how it works!

Comment: Dear mayank, in my code it says that it cannot solve mothode 'getactivity()' Do you have any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: where are you use this code in activity or fragment??

Comment: Thank you Mayank, I think I found my own error about getactivity() it wasn't on the right place :D

Comment: In fragment... but I have one question, what does dataAdapterSeat exactly ?

Comment: it is array adapter object for mine naming convening , you can take anythings.